# Simple form; Save and continue later data

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm trying to make an attendance form where the user of the system inputs the data of the students then if there is an emergency (or whatever the reason why he needs to quit the system)he just needs to close the browser and continue later with the data still on the form. In order to do that, I used the garlic.js (which  was suggested on this website too). The instruction on the garlicjs.org is simple yet I cannot make my form work.

I'm retrieving the data from the database and prints it through a table. This is my code

```
<form name="result"  data-persist="garlic" method="post" id="form"> 
Date: <input type="date" name="date" required="required" size="20" placeholder="Date"/><br>


   <?php
     if( $_POST["time_pm"] == ''){  ?>
        <table class="table table-striped">
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>ID #</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Time AM</th>
               <th>Time PM</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
      <?php 
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // output data of each row
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnames)) {
                 if($row['status']=='p'){                  
                  echo'<tbody>';
                   echo'<tr>';
                   echo '<td>' . $row['user_idnumber'] . '</td>';
                   echo '<td>' . $row['lastname'] . ', ' . $row['firstname'] . '</td>';
                   echo '<input type="hidden" name="selected[]" value="'.$row['user_idnumber'].'"/>';
                   echo '<td>' . ' <input type="time" name="time_am[]" required="required" placeholder="Score"/>' . '</td>';
                   echo '<td>' . ' <input type="time" name="time_pm[]" required="required" placeholder="Score"/>' . '</td>';
                 echo '</tr>';
             echo '</tbody>';
                            } //if statement
                          } //while statement
                     ?>
                  </table>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info"/>
                  </form>
```

This is just a simple form yet I cannot solve the problem here. The date input works fine but it does not work when it comes to the input time (for AM and PM). If I set the time for only few users and let the other users set to blank (continue later) and when I try to hit refresh, (the users)everyone else below gets the same time.